# package date in hex java

Tags: arrays, byte, bit-manipulation, android-calendar

currently developing a Android app in java whih requires sending the current time and date data across NFC in NDEF format. NDEF messages require sending the data over in raw hex. To make the best use of limited space and limited computing power of the receiving device, I have chosen to send the year as one byte (the year number minus 2000; i.e 2014 = 14, so the device is good for 255 years...). The simplest approach to getting a particular day I could think of was to grab the DAY_OF_YEAR and split into two bytes. When toasted to the screen, I dont appear to get a correct answer at all. The following is a commented Minimum working example.

```
  final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();         //grab an instance of calendar
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)-2000;              //get the year, and subtract 2000
        char[] bday = new char[2];                         //create a 2 byte character array for the day number
        byte byear= (byte) year;                           //convert int year to a single byte
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);             //get the day of the year
        Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "" + day, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  //Toast the day int, for debugging
        bday[0] = (char) day;                              //get the LSB of day int
        bday[1] = (char) (day>>>8);                        //get the MSB of day int

        String date = "y"+ byear "d" + bday[1] + bday[0];  //Toast the year (fine), and day (not right)
```

Comment: `bday[0] = (char)(day & 0XFF);  bday[1] = (char)((day>>8) & 0xFF);`

Comment: Thanks allot, had to change the char data types to byte to get the correct result but got it working now. thanks again.